# Magento 1 Override Poll controller is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I am trying to override the poll extension of magento but the override that i am doing is not working. My purpose is when someone complete's the poll to redirect him into a different url, instead of seeing the poll results.

So here you can see my folder structure http://prntscr.com/g5rz6w

Config.xml

```
<config>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <poll>
            <args>
                <module>
                  <Poll_MF_module before="Mage_Poll">Poll_MF_module_Poll</Poll_MF_module>
                </module>
            </args>
        </poll>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

VoteController.php

```
    require_once('Mage/Poll/controllers/VoteController.php');

class Poll_MF_Module_VoteController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
        die ('vote is dead');
    }
```

and inside the app/etc/modules/Poll_MF_Module.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Poll_MF_module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Poll_MF_module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your module name from **Poll_MF_module** to **Poll_Mf**

**app/code/local/Poll/Mf/etc/config.xml**  and not Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Poll_Mf>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Poll_Mf>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <poll>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <poll_mf before="Mage_Poll">Poll_Mf</poll_mf>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </poll>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Poll/Mf/controllers/VoteController.php**

```
require_once 'Mage/Poll/controllers/VoteController.php' ;

//here you extends the controller that you want to rewritte and not the natif one

class Poll_Mf_VoteController extends Mage_Poll_VoteController
{ 
    public function nameAction()
    {
        die ('vote is dead');
    } 
}
```

**app/etc/modules/Poll_Mf.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Poll_Mf>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Poll_Mf>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi, i did your suggestions but it's not working.

Comment: I updated my answer, look again, it should work

Comment: No it's not working. The poll is loaded normally in my page and works.

Comment: the answer that i gave you is correct, check your module files and of the extention too

Comment: I am loading the the above files into app/code/local/Poll_mf and not in app/code/local/Mage/Poll_Mf is that correct?

Comment: No like this (uppercase in module name ans not an underscore), it should be like this : `app/code/local/Poll/Mf`

Comment: look my update, i added you the path for each file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63482/discussion-between-prince-and-ebabis).

Comment: ok lets talk into chat